# VirtualBox under Ubuntu 12.04 has a problem in mounting an external USB-drive

Tags: virtualbox, usb-drive

I have installed VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. Now, I've bought an external USB-drive with 1.5 TB.

When I start Windows7 in VirtualBox and mount the new USB-drive, a popup-message appears, saying: "USB Device Not Recognized - One of the USB devices attached to this computer has malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it."

When I use the the USB-drive on Windows7 without VirtualBox, the drive works properly.

When I start Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox and mount the new USB-drive, nothing happens. The new drive neither appears, nor an error-message is thrown.

When I use the the USB-drive on Ubuntu 12.04 without VirtualBox, the drive works properly.

When I use other USB-drives (2 x 250 GB (USB2.0), 1 x 500 GB (USB2.0), 1 x 1 TB (USB3.0)) and mount them in VirtualBox they also work properly.

TIA

Comment: Workaround: mount the drive in Ubuntu, and share the mount point via the [VirtualBox Shared Folders](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)

Answer (score 1):

Things you can try:

- **Ensure the drive isn't using OS-specific firmware that requires the execution of an application for mounting**. This is a common feature on flash drive and Western Digital hard drives. In such a case, you should be able to disable this using the provided utilities.
- **Reduce the number of CPUs on the guest machine to one**. As per one of the messages on the link at the bottom, this has helped some people access their USB devices on their virtual guests.
- **Check "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) controller" in the guest's settings**. This has fixed quite a few problems for me personally, and is quite easy to miss in my opinion.
- **Add a USB filter for your storage device in your guests's settings.** This will ensure only your guest can access that connection to your storage device. I've used this when performing app debugging on my Android phone.

[USB Device not recognized](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=43159)